# How to center column cells differently in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, alignment

This is my `datagrid` which contains 7 columns, here is an image of content in my datagrid:

[image]

I applied next code:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  IsReadOnly="True" AlternatingRowBackground="#E0E4E5" AlternationCount="2"  GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" FontSize="16" RowHeight="35" SelectionUnit="FullRow" RowHeaderWidth="0" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gray" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#EBEBEB" CanUserAddRows="False" MinHeight="200" x:Name="dtgItems" Margin="15,0,4,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="Transparent" SelectionChanged="dtgItems_SelectionChanged"  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" EnableRowVirtualization ="False" >

            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                </Style>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#0091EA"/>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="DataGridCentering"/>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrdinalNumber}"   Header="OrdinalNumber"   Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="10*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ArticleCode}"   Header="Code"   Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="10*"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ArticleTitle}"     Header="Title"   Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="40*"   />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity, StringFormat=N2}"       Header="Qty"   Foreground="Black"      FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="10*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price, StringFormat=N2}"   Header="Price"      Foreground="Black"     FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="10*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Discount, StringFormat=N2}"    Header="Discount"  Foreground="Black"           FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana"  Width="10*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TotalAmount, StringFormat=N2}"    Header="Total"  Foreground="Black"           FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana"  Width="10*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

as its possible to noticed I applied

```
VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  on my `DataGrid` so all of my content is alligned center, but I would like to align `VerticalContentAlignment="Left"` to some of my cells/column, for example I would like to align Title to Left..
```

So how could I apply different alignment on different cell/column?

Thanks guys,
Cheers

P.S I tried with this:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="LeftAlignCell" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    </Style>

<DataGrid.Resources>
```

AND

```
ElementStyle="{StaticResource  LeftAlignCell}"
```

I applied ElementStyle to my `DataGridTextColumn`

But I received following error : Requested value left was not found. So I guess it is not working this way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want

```
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
```

because it is the horizontal alignment,  not the vertical one you're speaking about

Comment: now I'm facing next trouble: APPlication is crushing when I run it after editing my  code, I changed setter as you said and added ElementStyle="{StaticResource  LeftAlign}"  to a DatagGridTextColumn and after that app is crushing on run xD

Comment: So it *compiles* now...you've solved the error posted in the question, haven't you? Is this crash a different issue? Accept this as answer and open  a different specific question with the new *details*

Comment: true, it compiles now, but when I try to apply  it application crushing, what do you think, what might be issue? and its definately when I try to apply ElementStyle, when I remove that line, application is not crushing anymore.. :)

Comment: Consider also the following `CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftAlignCell}"`